# Why Minecraft 1.12.2 crash when i execute runClient without touching the default code?

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft, minecraft-forge

My game keeps crashing every time i execute runClient command but I didn't modify anything in the code yet. I noticed that the error wasn't really coming from the mod (i tried to start the game without the @Mod annotation but it crashed with the same error), so I thought it was a problem with my pc, so I tried it on another pc and even reset my pc but it didn't worked. I'm completely lost:

```
 ---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Why did you do that?

Time: 1/17/24 5:10 PM
Description: There was a severe problem during mod loading that has caused the game to fail

net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoaderExceptionModCrash: Caught exception from Forge Mod Loader (FML)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.network.NetworkRegistry.newChannel(NetworkRegistry.java:207)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.network.internal.FMLNetworkHandler.registerChannel(FMLNetworkHandler.java:185)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLContainer.modConstruction(FMLContainer.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:91)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$SynchronizedSubscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:150)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$1.run(Subscriber.java:76)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:399)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.dispatchEvent(Subscriber.java:71)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Dispatcher$PerThreadQueuedDispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:116)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:217)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:219)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:91)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$SynchronizedSubscriber.invokeSubscriberMethod(Subscriber.java:150)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber$1.run(Subscriber.java:76)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:399)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Subscriber.dispatchEvent(Subscriber.java:71)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.Dispatcher$PerThreadQueuedDispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:116)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:217)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:136)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Loader.loadMods(Loader.java:595)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.beginMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:232)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.init(Minecraft.java:467)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:378)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:123)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.Main.start(Main.java:86)
    at net.minecraftforge.legacydev.MainClient.main(MainClient.java:29)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.12.2
    Operating System: Windows 11 (amd64) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_392-392, OpenLogic-OpenJDK
    Java VM Version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 294443312 bytes (280 MB) / 910163968 bytes (868 MB) up to 3795845120 bytes (3620 MB)
    JVM Flags: 0 total; 
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    FML: MCP 9.42 Powered by Forge 14.23.5.2860 5 mods loaded, 5 mods active
    States: 'U' = Unloaded 'L' = Loaded 'C' = Constructed 'H' = Pre-initialized 'I' = Initialized 'J' = Post-initialized 'A' = Available 'D' = Disabled 'E' = Errored

    | State | ID         | Version      | Source                                                      | Signature |
    |:----- |:---------- |:------------ |:----------------------------------------------------------- |:--------- |
    | LC    | minecraft  | 1.12.2       | minecraft.jar                                               | None      |
    | LC    | mcp        | 9.42         | minecraft.jar                                               | None      |
    | LE    | FML        | 8.0.99.99    | forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12.jar | None      |
    | L     | forge      | 14.23.5.2860 | forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12.jar | None      |
    | L     | examplemod | 1.0          | main                                                        | None      |

    Loaded coremods (and transformers): 
    GL info: ' Vendor: 'ATI Technologies Inc.' Version: '4.6.0 Compatibility Profile Context 23.12.1.231124' Renderer: 'AMD Radeon RX 6700 XT'
[17:10:14] [Client thread/INFO] [STDOUT]: [net.minecraft.init.Bootstrap:printToSYSOUT:553]: #@!@# Game crashed! Crash report saved to: #@!@# C:\Users\tonib\Downloads\test\run\.\crash-reports\crash-2024-01-17_17.10.14-client.txt

> Task :runClient FAILED
```

While doing some research I noticed that I didn't have the file forge-1.12.2-14.23.5.2860_mapped_snapshot_20171003-1.12-recomp.jar in my gradle folder while I often see this file appearing in other people's logs on forums (no idea if it's related).
Thanks in advance for your time :)